# Override input element's focus-visible behaviour

Tags: html, css, accessibility

I'd like to remove the outline ring on an `input` element when focused via the mouse, but retain it when focused via the keyboard.

This [same question has been asked about a week ago here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76123040/input-fields-adding-focus-visible-on-click), with unfortunately no solution.

My case is slightly different, though.

**Input HTML:**

```html
<form class="custom-form">
  <label class="custom-label" for="my-input">
    <span>My Input</span>
    <input id="my-input" class="custom-input" name="my-input" type="number" min="0" max="100" value="00.00" step="1.00" required 
      aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
  </label>
</form>
```

**Input TailwindCSS:**

```less
.custom-form {
  @apply flex flex-row;
}
.custom-form .custom-label {
  @apply flex flex-col space-y-1;
}
.custom-form .custom-label > span {
  @apply pl-1;
}
.custom-form .custom-input {
  @apply max-w-[100px];
  @apply mr-2 px-1 py-[3px];
  @apply text-base;
  @apply border rounded border-gray-200 dark:border-neutral-600 focus:border-neutral-600 dark:focus:border-neutral-100;
  @apply outline-none;
  /*@apply focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2;
  @apply focus-visible:outline-neutral-600 dark:focus-visible:outline-neutral-100;*/
  @apply bg-neutral-100 dark:bg-neutral-700;
  @apply transition-all duration-75;
}
.custom-form input[type=number].custom-input {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
  appearance: textfield;
}
```

As you can see, I'm already applying a `border` on `focus` state which passes [W3's Relationship to Non-text Contrast Success Criterion](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG22/Understanding/focus-appearance-minimum).

This same focus style is applied to the rest of my UI elements but those still retain the outline ring when the keyboard is used for navigation.

Example:

**Button HTML:**

```html
<button class="custom-button">
  Button
</button>
```

**Button TailwindCSS:**

```less
.custom-button {
  @apply px-3 py-1 rounded;
  @apply bg-neutral-100 hover:bg-neutral-200 active:bg-neutral-300;
  @apply dark:bg-neutral-900 dark:hover:bg-neutral-700 dark:active:bg-neutral-600;
  @apply border border-gray-200 dark:border-neutral-600;
  @apply focus:border-neutral-600 dark:focus:border-neutral-100;
  @apply focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2;
  @apply focus-visible:outline-outline-light dark:focus-visible:outline-outline-dark;
  @apply transition-all duration-75;
}
```

Basically, I want the same style behavior of the `button` to be applied to the `input` element.

**Practical and possible alternatives:**

1. Remove and do not use any outline rings on any elements and stick to only the `border` styling via `focus` state.

I'd rather not do this, as the outline is easier to spot when navigating *fast* using the keyboard.

2. Add outline rings to the rest of the UI elements (where applicable).

Using outlines for everything, requires leaving more space between elements in order for things not to overlap and it also ruins the minimalistic style I'm going for.

3. Set the default outline to `none` via CSS and add a JavaScript `Tab` key listener to each `input` element and whenever said element receives focus that way, "enable" the outline.

I'm willing go with this last option as a last resort, but I don't know how much this would impact performance. I have about maximum of a dozen `input` fields per form.

Can the `:focus-visible` behavior even be changed in the first place? From what I've read, every browser does things differently.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the blue outline on focus, you can add the following CSS:

```
input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```